# Python вложенные списки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вечер добрый. Есть список mas, в который вложены еще три списка. Нужно составить список d таким образом, чтобы он состоял из первых элементов вложенных в mas списков.

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    d[i] = mas[i][0]
```

В этом случае он ругается на "IndexError: list assignment index out of range". Не понимаю, в чем проблема.

Comment: Что такое `d`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Циклом:

```
d = []
for i in mas:
    if len(mas[i]):
        d.append(mas[i][0])
```

Но лучше генератором:

```
d = [i[0] for i in mas if len(i)]
```

Comment: `len` можно не использовать, проверяя как `bool`